# Install J9 JRE in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, j9

Searching the web for tutorials on how to use J9 as a JRE within Eclipse, I found some websites and forums like the following:

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t98578.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/sametime-eclipse-pt1/

The solution is to add a j9 launcher plugin to eclipse that - according to the tutorials - can be downloaded from the following link: 
http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.ercp/org.eclipse.jdt.launching.j9/org.eclipse.jdt.launching.j9-plugin.zip?root=DSDP_Project&view=log

The problem is that this link is dead and I can't find this file anywhere else. Can anyone tell me where to get this file?

Comment: Weird, there are not many post-2007 traces of this plugin that I could find. Maybe merged into JDT and you don't need any plugins anymore, have you tried just adding it as a jdk? Anyways, I remember working with J9 from IntelliJ IDEA, and all went smooth.

Comment: Adding it as a normal JRE/JDK doesn't work, I already tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J9 launcher plug-in is not available now. Instead, you can configure j9 as JRE in eclipse using 'execution environment description' file - .ee file.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/J9

You can find the detail in the above link. But I'm not sure it's still valid in the latest eclipse version.